# Finding a number $M$ such that $S_N<10^{-20}$ for all $N>M$

Tags: summation

> Given that
>
> $$u_n=\frac{1}{n^2-n+1} - \frac{1}{n^2+n+1}$$
>
> $$S_n=\sum_{n=N+1}^{2N} u_n$$
>
> Find a number $M$ such that $S_N<10^{-20}$ for all $N>M$

---

I did:

$$S_N = \sum_{n=N+1}^{2N} u_n = \sum_{n=0}^{2N} u_n - \sum_{n=0}^{N} u_n$$

Using method of difference and by further simplification I get :

$$S_N= 1 - \frac{1}{(2N)^2+2N+1} - 1 + \frac{1}{N^2+N+1}$$

$$S_N= \frac{1}{N^2+N+1} - \frac{1}{4N^2+2N+1}$$

Then:

$$S_N < \frac{1}{10^{20}}$$

I did an assumption that:

$$\frac{1}{10^{20}} \approx 0$$

> Because without the assumption I end up with : $4N^4+7N^3+7N^2+3N+1 > 10^{20} (3N^2+N)$ which is like way too hard

I think it's pretty good approximation for such a question

Therefore :

$$\frac{1}{N^2+N+1} <  \frac{1}{4N^2+2N+1}$$

$$4N^2+2N+1 < N^2+ N+1$$

$$3N^2+N<0$$

$$\frac{-1}{3} < N < 0$$

So :

$$M=\frac{-1}{3}$$

$$\frac{3N^2+N}{(N^2+N+1)(4N^2+2N+1)} < \frac{1}{10^{20}}.$$

This is wrong. The correct answer is very large, it's:

$$M=10^{10}.$$

I have no idea how this number came, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$M=8.7\cdot10^9$ will do. To see this, note that $4N^2+2N+1\lt4(N^2+N+1)$ hence $$S_N= \frac{1}{N^2+N+1} - \frac{1}{4N^2+2N+1}\lt\frac34\frac{1}{N^2+N+1},$$ and $S_N\lt10^{-20}$ for every $N$ such that $$N^2+N+1\gt\frac34\cdot10^{20},$$ and it suffices to ask that 
$$N\gt\sqrt{\frac34}\cdot10^{10}.$$ Of course, the cruder bound $10^{10}$ works, since $$S_N\lt\frac{1}{N^2+N+1}\lt\frac{1}{N^2},$$ hence $N\geqslant10^{10}$ implies $S_N\lt10^{-20}$.

Comment: Didn't quite get this :/ Still thinking :)

Comment: Please do. The trouble with the accepted answer is that it is based on asymptotics hence one cannot be sure that the value proposed fits, for any fixed error. Did not you ask for a specific error (namely, 10^-20)?

Comment: Took me a while :D this is SOOOO awesumly done :D I love UR answer. Thank you so much

Comment: Did, do you know why my method didn't work out? :)

Comment: The first wrong step might be to assert that
$$\frac{1}{N^2+N+1} <  \frac{1}{4N^2+2N+1}.$$

Comment: Ummmm but that was because of my approximation :/

Answer (score 2):

It's much easier to see that for large $N$, the $N^2$ term dominates, so that we solve:

$$\frac{1}{N^2}-\frac{1}{4N^2}=\epsilon$$
Or:
$$N=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt{\epsilon}}=8.66025 \times 10^9$$

Comment: Ohhhhhhhh :D got it :D

Comment: Any idea how $10^{10}$ came? :)

Comment: @TheArtist - round to the nearest factor of ten to get:  $8.6 \times 10^{9} \approx 10^{10}$.

Comment: Got it :D ;) Thanks :)